# Global symbol "%self" requires explicit package name in Perl module

Tags: perl, oop, perl-module

I'm writing a Perl module and I've come across this confusing error message while running my tests.

```
sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = @_;
  $word = $self{word} || die "No word provided.";
  @definitions = @{decode_json(get($urban_url . $word))->{'list'}} || die "Error during fetch/decode.";
  @tags = @{decode_json(get($urban_url . $word))->{'tags'}} || "Error during fetch/decode.";
  bless($self, $class);
  return $self;
}
```

As you can see, `$self` is declared properly. `word` is a global variable declared above the `new` subroutine. The failure occurs in every test at the `use` statement, and traces back to the assignment of `$word`.

Comment: Yeah, it does. Stupid mistake on my behalf. I changed it to `my ($class, %self) = @_;` and now it seems to be working.

Comment: Don't use `%self` name in this case. Use `%in` or `%params`.

Comment: @woodruffw: As Vadim says, don't use a hash called `%self`. `$self` is *always* a (scalar) blessed reference to the current object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scalar `$self` is declared, but you are using non-existing hash `%self`.

```
my $self = @_;
... $self{word} ...
```

should be

```
my %args = @_;
... $args{word} ...
```

---

Of course, you still need `$self`. You want it to be a reference to a new empty hash. You need:

```
my $self = {};     # Creates an anon hash and places a reference to it in $self.
```

---

Next, the following doesn't do what you want.

```
my @foos = @{ REF } || die(LIST);
```

The following will:

```
my @foos = @{ REF } or die(LIST);
```

The following will probably be more useful:

```
my $foos = REF or die(LIST);
```

---

Finally, you never actually store the data in your object.

```
my $data = decode_json(get($urban_url . $word));
   or die("Error during fetch/decode\n");

$self->{definitions} = $data->{list};
$self->{tags}        = $data->{tags};
```

---

After a few style changes, you get what I'd use.

```
sub new {
   my ($class, %args) = @_;

   my $word = $args{word}
      or die("No word provided");

   my $data = decode_json(get($urban_url . $word));
      or die("Error during fetch/decode\n");

   my $self = bless({}, $class);

   $self->{definitions} = $data->{list};
   $self->{tags}        = $data->{tags};

   return $self;
}
```

I lied. I doubt I would do a web request and the parsing of the response in an object constructor.

Comment: Much of what I said wasn't appropriate -- there were far more problems than I realized -- so I just made a major update.

Comment: Thanks again. I rewrote most of the module to act procedurally instead of object oriented, but this was still very helpful.